# AnalysisServices: Visually grouping of tables in tabular

Tags: ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services, analysisservices

We have a rather complex AnalysisServices tabular model with over 100 tables. We would like to group tables which belong to the same logical area visually together. Ideally PowerBI would then display expandable groups.

I have found 'Display Folders' only for measures within an AS Tabular model. Is there a way I can do the same on the table level?

Answer (score 0):

That specific functionality does not exist but the most similar one I know is [Perspectives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/perspectives-ssas-tabular?view=asallproducts-allversions).

A simple Use Case is to define Perspectives as subject area and specify which objects belong to each perspective. For example, you can define the Perspective Sales which contains all entities relevant to sales subject. Then the Perspective Marketing which contains all entities relevant to marketing subject.